# same js highcharts display not the same

Tags: javascript, jsp, highcharts

I use highcharts to display the date, now I generate the js code as below:

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function () {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'column',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: '终端类型统计'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['Apple', 'Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd', 'HTC Corporation', 'Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.,Ltd.', 'Intel Corporate', 'Xiaomi Technology,Inc.', 'Liteon Technology Corporation', 'Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd', 'Murata Manufactuaring Co.,Ltd.', 'Azurewave Technologies, Inc.', 'Huawei Device Co., Ltd', 'zte corporation', 'Lenovo Mobile Communication Technology Ltd.', 'GUANGDONG OPPO MOBILE TELECOMMUNICATIONS CORP.,LTD.', 'Azurewave', 'XIAOMI CORPORATION', 'Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB', 'Yulong Computer Telecommunication Scientific(shenzhen)Co.,Lt', 'AcSiP Technology Corp.', 'BBK Electronics Corp., Ltd.', '其他'],
                        labels: {
                            rotation: -25,
                            align: 'right',
                            style: {
                                fontSize: '13px',
                                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: '数据统计'
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            colorByPoint: true,
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                rotation: -90,
                                y: 25,
                                color: '#F4F4F4',
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
                                },
                                x: 10,
                                style: {
                                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    lang: {
                        decimalPoint: '.',
                        downloadPNG: '下载PNG图片',
                        downloadJPEG: '下载JPG图片',
                        downloadPDF: '下载PDF文件'
                    },
                    series: [{
                            showInLegend: false,
                            data: [581476, 407696, 277894, 247696, 168586, 138802, 126082, 93168, 76234, 51568, 51512, 50654, 49026, 47092, 44944, 43188, 41268, 40900, 39408, 38172, 580090],
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                rotation: -90,
                                color: '#FFFFFF',
                                align: 'right',
                                x: -3,
                                y: 10,
                                formatter: function () {
                                    return this.y;
                                },
                                style: {
                                    fontSize: '13px',
                                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
        });
})
```

It should be displayed like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HRrZz/), but in my page it [display like this] in ie 8 (https://i.minus.com/irfUdeWCLEGPD.png)!
Any ideas?
ps：、: it works fine in FireFox.

Comment: my eyes!!! please, fix that code.

Comment: Probably you have some conflicting class in your CSS

Comment: Do you use the same code, for both pages? It is possibel to take look at source on your webpage, not jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

If the Fiddle works, double-check your code, because it's hard to help in that case. Check your chrome console or firebug, and make sure the other javascript code on your page isn't interfering.

According to http://json.parser.online.fr/ the JSON object you use in your graph is ok. At least i cannot find any strange things in it... do you use the same Highcharts version?